# Form submitting using jquery without ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I am new to rails.i Want to sort content using jquery by selecting value from dropdown list.
so i am having problem to submit a form to a specific controller action using jquery.
I have a category model which has many products.In my category show i have a form like bellow:

```
    <%= form_for(:category, :url => sort_category_path, method: 'GET', :class=> " form-inline pull-left") do |f| %>
              Sort By :
              <select id ="sort" name= "order_by">
                <option>Default</option>
                <option>Name</option>
                <option>Pirce</option>

              </select>
  <%end%>
```

here at this form i am not sure what does mean by :category ?
Jquery for submit the form :

```
  $('select#sort').change(
function(e){

    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');

});
```

Then at my category controller i have a sort_item action like this:

```
  def sort_item
   @category_sort = Category.find(params[:id])

   @products = @category_sort.products.order("#{params[:order_by].to_s} ASC")
  end
```

i dont know how to send response to the request.
the server log says :

Started GET "/en/categories/tshart/sort_item?utf8=%E2%9C%93&order_by=Pirce" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-11 12:53:49 +0600
Processing by CategoriesController#sort_item as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_by"=>"Pirce", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"tshart"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`slug` = 'tshart' LIMIT 1

Redirected to http://test.com/en/categories/tshart
Filter chain halted as :find_category rendered or redirected
Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 6.7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

keep in mind that test.com stands for localhost:3000 .

i want to know what i am doing wrong here ,why the sorting is not working or is there any better way to accomplish my sorting task?

please help me . 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow its working now.
It was a routing issue I explained earlier.The issue was:

Redirected to http://test.com/en/categories/tshart Filter chain halted as :find_category rendered or redirected Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 6.7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Here my request was redirected to another action then i removed the the filter chain and then added render :show to my categories controller sort_item action. now its just rocking .Everything else remain the same.

Hope this question may help others.

Thanks @jai for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `change` event in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){ // <----enclosed in document ready
    $('select#sort').change(function(e){
       $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

This will look for if dom has been ready for js event execution bind on elements.

Comment: my bad.its already is in document ready.its hitting to the desired url   @jai